# What's the proper way of moving documents between databases starting from PyMongo 3.6?

Tags: python, database, pymongo

I used to use `pymongo.bulk.BulkOperationBuilder` but the docs say that it's deprecated.

The official [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.cloneCollection/) has `db.cloneCollection()` but I can't find anything similar in [PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/copydb.html), except `copydb` but it's not what I need.

So I found two ways to bulk insert docs between colls and removing them afterwards. I haven't tested them yet, I wanted to ask you firstly for an advice because there might be a better way.

Solution #1.

```
coll_from = mongo['db_1']['coll_name']
coll_to = mongo['db_2']['coll_name']
requests = (InsertOne(doc) for doc in coll_from.find())

result = coll_to.bulk_write(requests, ordered=False)
db_from.drop_collection('coll_name')
```

Solution #2.

```
coll_from = mongo['db_1']['coll_name']
coll_to = mongo['db_2']['coll_name']
coll_to.insert_many(coll_from.find())
db_from.drop_collection('coll_name')
```

Is there any better way to bulk-move docs between dbs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cloneCollection` as [documented](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/cloneCollection/#dbcmd.cloneCollection) is a command.

Pymongo API exposes a `command` method on an instance of `pymongo.database.Database`.

This can be applied in the following manner to clone a similarly named collection from a remote collection.

```
client = MongoClient()

clone_cmd = {
    'cloneCollection': 'db_1.coll_name',
    'from': '<hostname>'
}
client.db_2.command(clone_cmd)
```

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you.